# [Selenium][Java][PageObject] How to check if we have 'xyz' value ( of Web Element) on the list with values?

Tags: java, testing, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, pageobjects

I have created a test that adds  xyz1 , xyz2, xyz3 ....xyz(n)  element , what is presented  as a list on page. **I need to be sure that among these names exists element titled " xyz3"** (or titled different ,  what  I will define) 
My idea is to build list/ array /collection that will gather all values of web element and then I need to write a method that will looking for my defined "xyz3" among these values collected in list.
My web element:
[image]

```
  @FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "//div[@id='_field']")
public List <WebElement> listOfNames;

My attempts in creating a list :

LList<WebElement> myElements = createEvalTemplateLocators.getListOfNames();
    boolean temp1;
    for(WebElement e : myElements) {

        System.out.println(e.getText() + "");

    }

    for(WebElement e : myElements) {

        temp1 = e.getText().contains("temp1");

        if (temp1==true) System.out.println("hurray temp1 is on page ");
        else {System.out.println("something gone wrong with temp1");}
    }
```

RESULT IN CONSOLE:

[image]

I am not able to create better locator- more appropiate that will not 'take' element next to it...
Moreover I  want to know if on the list exist 'temp1' one at least only, info message about each entity is not neccessary.... 
I don't have any better ideas for my test, in the future I would like to use asserts for this case..

I am beginner :( and I am learning on my own mostly, so  could anybody help me with this case ?

( Greetings from Baltic Sea for All :))

Comment: Try with xpath `"//div[@id='_field']/span"`

Comment: Thanks for answer. Unfortunately it ends with the same result '- temp1' ' no '..

Comment: What `createEvalTemplateLocators.getListOfNames();` do?